# ESP01 fine when conected to PC, doesn't boot on battery

Tags: esp8266

I upload the program on an ESP01, works fine when connected to a PC (via the 3.3v programmer, all 4 wires connected). When I connect it to a battery or only on 2 wires from PC: VCC and GND - no TX/RX connection, some times it boots, most of the time doesn't boot. 3.3v from AMS1117 3.3 of course.
Any explanation?
PS Chip Enabled link-ed to 3.3v PIN.
Thank you

Comment: please add your connection diagram because it seems like a electronics issue instead of a programming one. (Also are you using the arduino ide?)

Comment: Seems like this is caused by low current or connection issue.  Clearly, this question has nothing to do with programming, and shouldn't be in StackOverflow. This is a question for `https://electronics.stackexchange.com/`

Answer (score 0):

- Are you using breadboard or so long cables? I had similar issue with long cables and breadboard.
- check if battery is strong powersupply.
- double check if VCC and GND connectors are soldered properly to board.

Comment: Got it. a 10k resistor on the ralay board prevented the normal mode of EPS01